# What's the area bounded by the curves $y^2=x^3$ and $x^2=y^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

What's the area bounded by by the  curves $y^2=x^3$ and $x^2=y^3$?

My Approach: 
$$y^2=x\cdot x^2=xy^3$$
$$\implies y^2-xy^3=0$$
$$y^2(1-xy)=0$$
I.e. $y=0$ or $xy=1$ (which is rectangular hyperbola).
What to do next?

Comment: Plot the curves $y=x^{3/2}$ and $y=x^{2/3}$. For the first curve you have solutions only for $x \ge 0$. The most straight forward approach is to find the area under the first curve and then take away the area under the second curve. You need to work out the limits for $x$ (where do they intersect?).

Answer (score 1):

$y^2= x^3$ is equivalent to $y= \pm x^{3/2}$ and it is $y= x^{3/2}$ that is relevant here.  $y^3= x^2$ is equivalent to $y= x^{2/3}$.  Yes, those cross at (0, 0) and (1, 1).  The region between them lies between x= 0 and x= 1, above $y= x^{3/2}$ and below $y= x^{2/3}$.  The area is $\int_0^1 \left(x^{2/3}- x^{3/2}\right)dx$.

Answer (score 0):

You should argue by symmetry. First work out $S$, the area bounded by $x$-axis, $x=1$ and $y=x^{3/2}$, then the result you want to know, $A$, is given by $1-2S$.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of $y^2=x^3$ is symmetrical with respect to the $x$-axis (with one part of the curve in the first quadrant and the other in the fourth) and $y^3=x^2$ is symmetrical with respect to the $y$-axis (with one part of the curve in the first quadrant and the other in the second). The bounded region is in the first quadrant and there you can rewrite the curves as:
$$y = x^{2/3} \quad , \quad  y = x^{3/2}$$
These curves intersect at $x=0$ and $x=1$ and for $0 \le x \le 1$, you have $x^{2/3} \ge x^{3/2}$ so the area is given by:
$$\int_0^1x^{2/3} - x^{3/2} \, \mbox{d}x = \cdots = \frac{1}{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach failed because we're not trying to *equate* the curves. Let's imagine that we were given the curves $y=1$, $y=0$, $x=1$ and $x=0$, they would bound a region: the unit square. Each curve here would define an edge of the square as a set of all the points that satisfy a certain rule, e.g. $(0.5,1), (0.6,1)$ and $(0.7,1)$ satisfy $y=1$. But if we wanted the set of points that satisfied the rules of *two* curves, this would necessarily be an intersection of edges, i.e. one of the square's corners. So by equating curves, we *lose* information about their shape, which doesn't help for integration problems.

Think about your problem geometrically and try to describe each region of space in terms of the curves that bound it. Then use one of the formulations given by the other answers.